# How to I solve this infinite loop in python for a mastermind game menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
    ans = True
    while ans:
        print("What would you like to do?")
        print("""
        r register a new user
        s show the score board
        p play  a game
        q quit
        """)
        ans = input("What would you like to do?")
        if ans=="r":
            """

            If user 1 chooses option 'r'

            """
            player_1 = input("What is the name of the new user?")
            print("Welcome", player_1, "!")
```

Hi,
I am coding a MasterMind game in python and ran into an infinite loop while coding the game menu. I am new to python so I might not have the best understanding of the concepts.

Comment: Set `ans` to `False`?

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition to exit. You need to update your `ans` in code to `False` to exit from loop.

```
elif ans == "q":
    ans = False
```